# SFML и Box2D используют пикселы для определения размера и позиции тела?

Tags: c++, sfml, box2d

У них одинаковая мера?
И как сделать точку отсчёта SFML не от левого верхнего угла, а от центра низа окна?
Так что бы SetPosition(0, 0) устанавливал фигуру не в верхний левый угол, а в центр низа окна.
Что бы при ширине окна 800, края были равны -400 и 400 пикселов.

Comment: Box2d c пикселями вообще не работает. Преобразованием координат придется заниматься самостоятельно.

Comment: Как же преобразовать его единицы в пикселы? Какую единицу он использует? А SFML использует пикселы?